# Consuming JavaScript code in TypeScript application

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, import

I'm learning TypeScript and as a practice I wanted to try to consume JavaScript code in my TS app.

For example, this is your .js file:

```
foo = function() {
    console.log("imported from Test.js");
};
```

I have managed to make it work with the following code:

//Test.js

```
module.exports.foo = function() {
    console.log("imported from Test.js");
};
```

//Test.d.ts

```
declare module 'Test' {
    export function foo(): void;
}
```

//HelloWorld.ts

```
import * as t from './Test';
t.foo();
```

This code executes fine but produces the following error which I cannot get rid of:

`Error:(1, 20) TS2306:File 'C:/Users/2512/Projects/TypeScript/Test.d.ts' is not a module.`

Also, if `module.exports` is used in Test.js then `foo()` cannot be called in Test.js as `foo();` as it produces a `foo is not defined` error.

My main question is, what is the most up-to-date practice to import .js code into .ts without making any modification to an existing .js file?

I've spent many hours looking for the answer but could not find an ideal solution. Thank you.

P.S. I have typings installed in the project so I believe `/// <reference path="Test.d.ts" />` is not required in `Test.ts`.